# Why my input give me error undifined when I use react-hook-form?

Tags: html, reactjs, validation, input, react-hook-form

My input below is written in react and I use react-hook-form but when I use handleSubmit, it gives me undifined error back.

```
<input
                        type="tel"
                        {...register(
                            "phoneSignIn",
                            {
                                required: true,
                                minLength: 10,
                                maxLength: 11,
                            },
                            { pattern: "[0-9]+" }
                        )}
                        control={control}
                    />
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0utg.jpg)

Comment: Could you add the exact error also?

Comment: It exactly says "undefined".

Comment: please attach the screenshot.

Comment: I added the screenshot. Check the post.

Comment: According to your attached screenshot, it's not an error, it is a log message. Are you trying to log anything? If yes, could you add that code also.

Comment: It's the error state that react-hook-form is giving back to me.